# Dropdown inside a dropdown in Foundation 5

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, zurb-foundation-5

I need a second hover dropdown inside an existing dropdown, so when I open first dropdown and hover a specific option it should open the second dropdown, but it doesn't, it just closes first dropdown.

**How can I have nested dropdowns in Foundation 5?**

My code:

```
<div data-dropdown="a" aria-expanded="false">Settings</div>

<ul id="a" class="f-dropdown" data-dropdown-content>
    <li><a href="/">Option</a></li>
    <li data-dropdown="b" data-options="is_hover:true">
        <a>Option</a>
        <ul class="f-dropdown" id="b">
            <li><a href="#">Option</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Option</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Option</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/">Option</a></li>
    <li><a href="/">Option</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Did you look at the source code of the first example in [top bar](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/topbar.html) ?

Answer (score 0):

According to me, "Top Bar" navigation in Foundatio 5 can help to answer this question.